# How to reduce size (ByteCount) of a number?

Tags: memory

How do I reduce the memory, reserved for a number?

```
In[23]:= ByteCount[RandomReal[{1, 9}, 1]]
ByteCount[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 1]]
ByteCount[Round[RandomReal[{1, 9}, 1], 0.01]]
ByteCount[Round[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 1], 0.01]]
ByteCount[Chop[RandomReal[{1, 9}, 1]]]
ByteCount[Chop[RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 1]]]

Out[23]= 112

Out[24]= 112

Out[25]= 112

Out[26]= 112

Out[27]= 64

Out[28]= 112
```

In this form a billion number takes all the RAM. 4 decimal place accuracy is enough for me. How do I reduce the memory usage per number so that I can upload few billion numbers?

```
In[30]:= ByteCount[RandomReal[{1, 9}, 10^9]]/(1024.^3)

Out[30]= 7.45058073103
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The standard `Real` is a 64-bit floating-point number (doubles).  There's `NumericArray[array, "Real32"]`, which will convert them to 32-bit FP (singles). Of course you can't convert a whole array of doubles without storing it as an array of doubles.  You'd have to chunk the conversion somehow. I haven't played with this type, but you can use `Join`, `Flatten`, `Part` etc on them.  If fixed-point will work for you, you could store them in 16-bit `"Integer16"` or `"UnsignedInteger16"` numeric arrays.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, without success. Would you please give me an explicit example how to use it properly?

Comment: `NumericArray[RandomReal[1, {5, 5}], "Real32"]`? (Adapted from the second example in the documentation of `NumericArray`.)

Comment: Allow me to back up one step. *Why* do you need to store that many numbers all at once? Maybe there is another approach to solve your actual problem that might not require this step.

Comment: @MarcoB: I'm looking to compute correlation and build model from close to a 100 GB data. Beyond 4th decimal place accuracy is not important.

Comment: Correlation is not a very precise concept. I suggest a much smaller random sample of your data will allow correlation computation which is accurate enough for you. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: @Somos: Well purpose of my task is not to select at random.

Comment: Could you break the correlation computation up into stages, so you only need to use a manageable amount of working memory at once?

Comment: Seeing that I don't have a direct solution, I may need to think in that direction.